# One-directional Transactional Replication is causing one table's Clustered Index to be copied over as a Nonclustered Index in the subscriber database?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication, clustered-index

This seems really odd to me, as I've used SQL Server's **replication** feature for a while now and have never seen this occur before.

I'm using One-Directional Transactional Replication and I have **ServerA** - the **Publisher**, and **ServerB** the **Subscriber** setup. I'm only replicating about 20 tables or so total.

In **ServerA**, `Table1` has a couple of **nonclustered indexes** on it (including the primary key itself), and a separate **clustered index**. When the snapshot is generated to create `Table1` on **ServerB**, all of it's indexes (even the **clustered index**) are created as **nonclustered** on the subscriber database in **ServerB**.

I even went so far as to take the following steps:

1. Removed `Table1` from the **Publication's Articles**
2. Dropped `Table1` from the **subscriber database**
3. Re-initialized and generated a new snapshot
4. Then re-added `Table1` with the **Article Properties** set to **false** for "*Copy nonclustered indexes*"
5. Then re-initialized and generated a new snapshot again

And it still recreated `Table1` on the **subscriber database** with it's **clustered index** as a **nonclustered index**. It did not copy any of its actual **nonclustered indexes** except the primary key (which again is defined as a **nonclustered index** in the **publisher's database**).

Here's some screenshots to show it (sorry for all the obfuscation):

**Table1 in Publisher vs Subscriber Database:**

[image: Table1 in Publisher vs Subscriber Database]

**Publisher Table1's sys.Indexes:**

[[image: Publisher Table1's ​sys.Indexes2]

**Subscriber Table1's sys.Indexes:**

[image: Subscriber Table1's sys.Indexes]

**Publication's Article Properties for Table1:**

[image: Publication's Article Properties for Table1]

What the heck is going on?

Comment: I replicated your scenario and for me it created with clustered index and primary key as non-clustered index

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's a bug in the SSMS; try to scritp the @schema_option and verity the proper value based on the list here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

[image]